# Deploy Ruby on Rails app to App Engine using Cloud Build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I'm trying to automate the deployment of a Ruby on Rails app to App Engine using Cloud Build.

My `app.yaml` looked like this,

```
runtime: ruby
env: flex
entrypoint: bundle exec rails server
```

But I'm getting this error,

> Step #1: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) There is a cloudbuild.yaml in the current directory, and the runtime field in /workspace/app.yaml is currently set to [runtime: ruby]. To use your cloudbuild.yaml to build a custom runtime, set the runtime field to [runtime: custom]. To continue using the [ruby] runtime, please remove the cloudbuild.yaml from this directory.

Then I tried to change the runtime to `custom` and add a Dockerfile as custom runtime needs a Dockerfile.

But now I'm getting an error saying,

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) A custom runtime must have exactly one of [Dockerfile] and [cloudbuild.yaml] in the source directory; [/home/milindu/Projects/ElePath-Ruby] contains both

Then I removed Dockerfile also. But now getting into this weird situation. You can see the 'Step #1:' is growing into several like stuck in a recursion.

[image: Error console]

Answer (score 2):

Cloudbuild.yaml should work with App Engine Flexible without the need to use a custom runtime. As detailed in the first error message you received, you cannot have an app.yaml and the cloudbuild.yaml in the same directory if you are deploying in a non-custom runtime, to remedy the situation, follow these steps:

1. Move your app.yaml and other ruby files into a subdirectory (use your
   original app.yaml, no need to use custom runtime)
2. Under your cloudbuild.yaml steps, modify the argument for app deploy
   by adding a third one specifying your app.yaml's path.

Below is an example:

```
==================FROM:

steps: 
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud' 
args: ['app', 'deploy'] 
timeout: '1600s' 
===================TO:

steps: 
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud' 
args: ['app', 'deploy', '[SUBDIRECTORY/app.yaml]'] 
timeout: '1600s'
```

Comment: Thanks @David, I tried this and it worked. Now the problem is, this is an open source project and I can't move all the codes into a subdirectory just for Cloud Build. Is there a workaround you can think of? Is there a way to keep just `app.yaml` in a subdir and do it or any other trick?

Comment: I do not have a workaround for you at this time. However, this might be possible by using custom run times and a Docker file but I understand this might not be ideal. If you believe this is something critical for you, you can create a feature request on [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) by giving some context and providing your use case.